Пишу программу, нужно добавить корзину
Всем привет, я пишу программу на питоне, в которой у меня есть база данных: таблица зарегистрированных пользователей и таблица товаров(продукции). Я не понимаю, как добавить корзину, в которой будут храниться товары для определенного пользователя. Или скорее понимаю, но не понимаю, как отслеживать пользователя, который добавил товар...

Ну, добавить таблицу «корзина» со столбцами «пользователь» и «товар», наверное?

нууууу, да? ахахаха, я это прекрасно понимаю, но как мне понять, что у конкретного пользователя лежит в его корзине? вот какой вопрос меня интересует. в плане, пример "пользователь с id 7 добавил товар №5 в корзину. чтобы пользователь с id 2 не видел товара №5 в своей корзине

Создать таблицу для элемента корзины, в которой будут внешние ключи к таблице пользователя и таблице товара
CREATE TABLE cart_item(
user_id INTEGER,
product_id INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES user(id)
FOREIGN KEY(product_id) REFERENCES product(id)
)

Получить товары одного пользователя из этой таблицы зная его id можно так:
SELECT product_id FROM cart_item WHERE user_id = ? 


это и правда работает, но у меня появляется немного другой вопрос: как отслеживать действия пользователя после входа в аккаунт? в плане, от имени администратора я понимаю, как получить данные, а как мне получить данные от имени пользователя? я после входа должен возвращать user_id в программу? я правильно понимаю? ну, это если вы конечно знаете ответ на вопрос

@АртёмКовалев - правило сайта: одна тема - один вопрос. Не задавайте вопросы в комментариях, создайте новую тему для этого.

@AlexanderPetrov, хорошо, понял вас, извиняюсь
